# Should you delete questions or answers which get many downvotes?

Tags: discussion

Should you? Huh?

Comment: Don't do it! You get a stinky badge for it!

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: We don't need no stinky badges!

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to figure that out if it ever happens. (Actually, I have had [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538870/java-static-methods-best-practices/538909#538909) get down to -3; since it was actually correct but unsourced, I just edited it to explain myself better and it ended up at +6.)

Comment: I have one -3. I keep hoping for it to go down to -10 or so, but most people just leave argumentative comments.

Comment: @Aarobot: Why would you want one to go down?

Comment: @Billy: For fun, mostly. I think every user should have at least one black-sheep question/answer. It also helps that I *really* disliked the question, so downvotes are kind of an encouragement.

Comment: there should be a badge for -10 cause it's hard to achieve... most poeople are too nice

Comment: @Earlz: I aim to change that. Stay tuned for my upcoming speech. ;)

Comment: @Billy: delete questions if you want, but don't be too hasty to do it. The one you so quickly deleted today after getting a couple of downvotes, I was about to upvote and add an encouraging comment. I thought it was a fine question. So I say just let them hang around for a while and see what happens.

Comment: I think, no one has asked the OP here, what does it means "many" downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're bad questions / wrong answers, then yes.

Otherwise... maybe.  Hopefully somebody was nice enough to leave a comment.  If they did, you should be able to understand why people downvoted you and decide whether you can improve the question/answer, or whether you should just delete it.

Oh, and you get the Peer Pressure badge for deleting, so if you like badges, then go for it.

Comment: Well I didn't *think* it was a bad question but....

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I've got dozens of answers that I've deleted that I thought weren't bad at first but turned out on subsequent reads to be not so good. The same could go for questions. If you provide a link, I'd be happy to try to provide some constructive criticism.

Comment: @Randolpho: There was a question I asked a few minutes ago on Meta which received two downvotes in less than 10 mins. I deleted the question already unfortunately. But after deleting it, I considered asking **this** question :)

Comment: @Billy, downvotes on Meta don't mean it is a bad question. It just means they disagree with what you were suggesting. In your case, was it the 'Pay rep for extra votes' question? Theres nothing wrong with posting a suggestion some people disagree with, but if you're worried about your rep, just make it CW.

Comment: Ah, I thought this was about a Stack Overflow question.  Meta's different, I wouldn't delete a Meta question just because it got a few downvotes.

Comment: @Brandon: Not worried about Rep. But I am worried about looking like a complete idiot :)

Comment: @Billy ONeal: You know... I'd like to comment on a "Pay rep for extra votes" question. You should undelete it.

Comment: @Randolpho: How do I do that?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: You'd have to re-submit it unless you have +10k rep. (I think)

Answer (score 2):

I usually will delete a post if I later figure out I completely misunderstood the question.

If my solution just isn't correct then I like to leave it as a "what-not-to-do" and mark it as CW so I don't lose any more rep. I think it's unfair to edit my completely wrong suggestion to basically just copy off of the one that has upvotes.

Also, for questions they usually get closed and if they continue getting downvotes, then I mark it as CW if I think someone else will stumble upon it. If it's closed as subjective or something like that though, I'll usually delete it

Comment: +1 for leaving (a clearly marked) wrong answer. Chances are that it will be a common misunderstanding so having it there along with the correct answer can only help the community.